# rules deterministic finite automata

Tags: regex

A regular expression (ab)* (ba)*   can this contain string such as "aabbaaba" or 
does the *a's* always will not come between *b's* and does (ab)* mean that any number of 
*a's* and any number of *b's* or equal number of *a's* and *b's* . thanks for answering!

Answer (score 2):

Excluding the space in the middle, that is any number of "ab" strings followed by any number of "ba" strings.  So it would match things like `abababbababa`.  With the space, it would match `ababab bababa`.

There are online testers for regular expressions you can try, like this one.  You can try out your RegEx "live"

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

It's good for experimenting.